# Chart.js canvas y axis

Tags: jquery, canvas, chart.js

[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jraPu.png)

```
yAxes: [{

         ticks : {
                reverse : true,
                max: 100,
                stepSize: 10,
                autoSkip : true,
                drawOnChartArea : true,
                drawTicks : true,
                scaleOverride:false
        }
}]
```

As you see picture, I want to remove that area but remain max size 100.
what can I use options to remove?

Comment: remove max:100 then it will scale automatically

Comment: that means literally hardcoded

Comment: Use `max: 50,` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Please try below link for generate graph. You can make graph using drag- drop and select properties

http://charts.livegap.com/app.php?lan=en

I hope it help